# Applying Neural network for doing Image recognition

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

How is image recognition done by neural network after doing canny edge detection of the image? I don't seek for the code, I want to know how neural networks actually work in order to match similarity of the image from a set of images.

What should be considered in input layer, hidden layers, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

This question is really wide. The main reason why neural networks are doing so great job in this issue is taking advantage of some **intrinsic image properties** and **invariances** as well as **computational advances** which makes this issue possible to deal with :

1. **Hierarchical structure :** Faces consists of eyes, mouth, ears, etc. Eyes consists of a certain set of shapes, which consist of certain kind of edges, lines.. etc. There is a certain hierarchy of different shapes, structures etc. which are used for image recognition - and this is why deep stacked neural networks are so good in dealing with this task - this hierarchy is coded in a structure of neural network.
2. **Geometrical invariances :** If you move an image of a car from a left corner to a right corner - you will still have an image of a car. This property is a reason of success of a certain kind of neural networks - **convolutional** ones. This kind of ANN topologies makes use of this invariances making learning so easy and powerful.
3. **Increased computational power :** Today's convolutional neural networks are designed in a way which makes computations very easy to do in a parallel way. Also modern **GPU's architecture** makes learning really fast - sometimes up to **10x faster** than classical CPU implementations.

You can read a detailed explaination [here](http://learning.eng.cam.ac.uk/pub/Public/Turner/Teaching/ml-lecture-3-slides.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You question is really very broad. Also, from this line of your question, `How is image recognition done by neural network after doing canny edge detection of the image?`, it can be inferred that you are new to neural networks and deep learning. Neural networks do not specifically perform canny edge detection.

I recommend that before jumping into convolutional neural networks (CNNs), you understand some basics of neural networks. This way you will be able to appreciate CNN concepts later. [CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io) course could be a very good starting point for you, as basics of neural networks are also covered in that course.

It is really hard to write any specific answer for your broad question. Let me know if you have some specific questions.